# WPF Use same button style from usercontrol resources, but add triggers for changing images for each individual button

Tags: wpf, triggers, user-controls, styles

I'm trying to create a button that changes the color of an icon (White to Black) when a user clicks on the button. I already have a pre-set style of the button in my usercontrol resources that I don't want to modify. I just need the icon color to change, in which I used two of the same images with different colors.

```
   <UserControl.Resources>


        <!--Extended Button Style from Infragistics MetroDark Style-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="8"/>
                    <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="8"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter x:Name="ImageDefault"
                            Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter x:Name="ImageOnClick"
                            Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

and here's my button down below after the user control resources:

```
        <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="CalibrationMain">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Name="ImageDefault"
                       Source="pack://application:,,,/Images;component/Icons/UnknownSize/CalibrationIconWhite.png"
                       Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Visibility="Visible"/>
                <Image Name="ImageOnClick"
                       Source="pack://application:,,,/Images;component/Icons/UnknownSize/CalibrationIconBlack.png"
                       Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Text="Calibration"
                           FontSize="18"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

How can I get the "ImageDefault" to collapse and "ImageOnClick" to be visible when a user is depressing the left mouse click on the button without changing the parent style? Is there a more efficient and organized way of doing this?

I can't get it to work using x:Name or TargetName within the user control resources cause of the scope.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you need. It is typical for a Button to change IsPressed on click. But when UP, the state will return to the previous one. If you need to switch states on click, then I think you need ToggleButton and its IsChecked property. That is, your explanation is needed, what should happen after UP the button? Return ImageDefault?

Comment: @EldHasp Sorry about the super late reply. I was at work and couldn't answer right away. Also apologize that the question wasn't clear enough. What I'm trying to do is that I have a button with an icon (colored white) and a text underneath on a user control. When a user clicks on the button the icon should turn black when the button is depressed. I'm trying to find a way to do this without changing the overall style of the button as I'm using a style that is made up already from another resource file within the project. I have multiple buttons like this with their own separate icons.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer my request for more clarification on which property you want to react to: the [ButtonBase.IsPressed property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or the [ToggleButton.IsChecked property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).
In the Style XAML you showed, you tried to create a trigger on the `IsPressed` property, so I'm answering on the assumption that you need
`ButtonBase.IsPressed`.

Here is a XAML example:

```xml
    <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
            CommandParameter="CalibrationMain">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Name="ImageDefault"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Visibility="Visible">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                Value="pack://application:,,,/Images;component/Icons/UnknownSize/CalibrationIconWhite.png"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source"
                                        Value="pack://application:,,,/Images;component/Icons/UnknownSize/CalibrationIconBlack.png"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Text="Calibration"
                        FontSize="18"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

It is also possible to transfer the visualization of the button content to a common style:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <!--Images for all buttons-->
        <ImageSource x:Key="imageDefault">/someImageDefault.png</ImageSource>
        <ImageSource x:Key="imageIsPressed">/someImageIsPressed.png</ImageSource>
                
        <!--Extended Button Style from Infragistics MetroDark Style-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource button.ContentTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="8"/>
                    <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="8"/>
                </Style>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="button.ContentTemplate">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="PART_Image"
                                Width="100"
                                Height="100"
                                Visibility="Visible"
                                Source="{DynamicResource imageDefault}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Text="{Binding}"
                                    FontSize="18"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                                        Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource imageIsPressed}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

```xml
    <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
            CommandParameter="CalibrationMain" Cursor="Hand"
            Content="Calibration">
        <Button.Resources>
            <!--Images for this button only-->
            <ImageSource x:Key="imageDefault">pack://application:,,,/Images;component/Icons/UnknownSize/CalibrationIconWhite.png</ImageSource>
            <ImageSource x:Key="imageIsPressed">pack://application:,,,/Images;component/Icons/UnknownSize/CalibrationIconBlack.png</ImageSource>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I'll try to implement this and see if this will work. I'll will try the second solution that you provided.